# Raspberry pi network instability

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, ping, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 4 which is running raspbian. I am using the device as a local server inside my network so the device is always on. The setup works great but every few hours the raspberry pi can no longer be reached via SSH until I restart the pi. I assumed this was just the pi not connecting back to the internet after it disconnects so I set it to restart anytime it fails to ping the router. However, I setup a temporary monitor and keyboard to the pi and it turns out that when this internet issue occurs the pi can still ping the router (and other devices connected to the router), it's just that other devices cannot ping it. Any suggestions for how I can fix this?

I should also mention the pi is using wifi (and cannot be connected via ethernet).

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have an unreliable PI, it turns out to be the power supply.

They must have a USB-C adapter with 5.1v 3.0A 15.2w

A lot of cheaper adapters fall short of the above. Try with another power adapter first.

Comment: Physical connector is not relevant. The voltage should ideally be 5.0V for USB, although slightly higher one won't hurt.

Comment: It is very relevant. Try seeing how stable a Pi is on 5v 1a. It's not about the voltage, it's about the amps.

Comment: What does that have to do with the connector though?

Comment: They can be powered by wiring up the pins, but USB-C is the standard on a PI-4.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will order a new one.  However, I'm not particularly optimistic that this is the issue because when it's unreachable from exterior devices, the pi can still ping out.  I don't see how insufficient power supply would cause the device to not be pinged while still allowing it to ping out other devices.

Comment: New power adapter did not solve the issue.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: try using a USB wireless adapter instead of the built in wifi.